# Geoprocessor object won't execute

Tags: arcgis-10.1, c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, geoprocessing

I've tried several different approaches to getting the simple geoprocessing package that I created to execute from my C# project . . .

```c#
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor _localGPService = null;
        string gpkPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoPackageLocation"];
        string geoObjectPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoProcessorObject"];
    LocalGeoprocessingService.GetServiceAsync(gpkPath, GPServiceType.Execute, (gpService) =>
    {
        if (gpService.Error != null)
        {
         MessageBox.Show(gpService.Error.Message);
        }
        _localGPService = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor(gpService.UrlGeoprocessingService + geoObjectPath);
        DataContext = this; 
    });
    List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters = new List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter>();
    _localGPService.ExecuteAsync(parameters);
```

I've also tried the following . . .

```c#
 private LocalGeoprocessingService _localGPService = null;
    string gpkPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoPackageLocation"];
    _localGPService = new LocalGeoprocessingService(gpkPath, GPServiceType.Execute);

    _localGPService.StartAsync((callback) =>
    {
        if (callback.Error == null)
        {
            CoverButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error starting gp service");
        }
    });
    string geoObjectPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoProcessorObject"];
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor(_localGPService.UrlGeoprocessingService + geoObjectPath);
   List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters = new List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter>();
   gp.ExecuteAsync(parameters);
```

When it gets to the last line (execute), I don't get an error, but it also doesn't do anything.  I've been tracing through the code, and the geoprocessor object does get created and invoked with a URL, so I don't know why it does nothing. Tracing through, it appears as if everything is OK.  The tool that the gpk was created from runs OK when I execute it in ArcMap.
Any ideas as to what might cause this? I just don't know what to look for anymore.
Thanks!

Comment: I did check the box for ArcGIS Runtime. This is a simple test (I was not able to get my original tool to run). I created a simple model using Modelbuilder, that just uses the CopyFeatures tool to make a copy of a polygon. There are no inputs or output parameters. It runs successfully in ArcMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, the gpk was executing and producing a result, but the result was just not being written out to file geodatabase indicated in the model.  I was able to solve this problem by manipulating the object ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer once the gpk was finished executing.  Here is the code . . .

```
   public ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer;
        // Check for existence of local geoprocessing package name and start local gpk

        string gpkPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoPackageLocation"];
        string geoObjectPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoProcessorObject"];
        _localGPService = new LocalGeoprocessingService(gpkPath, GPServiceType.SubmitJob);


        _localGPService.StartAsync((callback) =>
        {
            if (callback.Error == null)
            {
                CoverButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error starting service");
            }
        });
        string geoObjectPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EsriRuntimeGeoProcessorObject"];
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor(_localGPService.UrlGeoprocessingService + geoObjectPath);
        gp.OutputSpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
        List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters = new List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter>();
          SubmitJobAsyncMethod(gp, parameters);

    private void SubmitJobAsyncMethod(ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor gp, List<ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPParameter> parameters)
    { 
        gp.JobCompleted += _localGPService_JobCompleted;
        gp.SubmitJobAsync(parameters); 
    }

   private void _localGPService_JobCompleted(object sender, JobInfoEventArgs e)
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor geoprocessorTask = sender as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor;
        geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataCompleted += _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted;
        geoprocessorTask.GetResultDataAsync(e.JobInfo.JobId, "Output_Cover_Areas");
    }

    private void _localGPService_GetResultDataCompleted(object sender, GPParameterEventArgs e)
    {
        _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer = e.Parameter as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GPFeatureRecordSetLayer;
            foreach (Graphic aGraphic in _gpFeatureRecordSetLayer.FeatureSet.Features)
            {
                DisplayGraphicOnMap(aGraphic);
            }                      
    }

    public void DisplayGraphicOnMap(Graphic graphic)
    {
        //Add input graphic to the map
        graphic.Symbol = this.Resources["InputPolygonSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.SimpleFillSymbol;
        _graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
        _map.ZoomTo(graphic.Geometry);
        _graphicsLayer.Refresh();
    }
```